# MouseBinding in TexBox within ItemsControl does not work WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have my MainWindow which has an ItemsControl for my EngineersUserControl (Engineers_UC) along with other controls. My Engineers_UC consists of a few TextBoxes for which I want to add MouseBinding with the aim of being able to left click on a TextBox and another method in my ViewModel to be executed. I have read that the issue might be that the elements of ItemsControl are not focusable but I haven't found a solution. Any ideas ?

MainWindow:

```
 <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <UserControl:Ribbon_UC Loaded="Ribbon_UC_Loaded" Margin="0,0,0,70"/>
        <UserControl:Calendar_UC/>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Engineer}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <UserControl:Engineers_UC />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Engineers_UC:

```
 <TextBox Name="EngineerName" IsReadOnly="True" Style="{StaticResource StyleTrigger} Text ="{Binding FULLNAME}">
           <TextBox.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding Command="{Binding EngineerCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=EngineerName}" MouseAction="{Binding EngineerCommand.MouseGesture}"/>
                </TextBox.InputBindings>
 </TextBox>
```

EngineerCommand:

```
void RelayCommands()
    {
        EngineerCommand = new SimpleDelegateCommand(x => EngineerFunction(x))
        {
            MouseGesture = MouseAction.LeftClick
        };
    }

  void EngineerFunction (object _engineername)
    {
        EngineerNameClicked = (_engineername as TextBox).Text;

    }
public class SimpleDelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    public Key GestureKey { get; set; }
    public ModifierKeys GestureModifier { get; set; }
    public MouseAction MouseGesture { get; set; }

    Action<object> _executeDelegate;

    public SimpleDelegateCommand(Action<object> executeDelegate)
    {
        _executeDelegate = executeDelegate;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _executeDelegate(parameter);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) { return true; }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any binding error in output windows while debugging?

Comment: @user1672994 Hello, no i do not get any errors. When i left click on the TextBox I am able to select the text, it does not recognise the TextBox as being clickable if you like. The code above has been tested in a different example where the TextBox was not part of an ItemsControl and it worked fine.

Comment: So where is the EngineerCommand defined?

Comment: @mm8 The EngineerCommand is defined in my View Model. I have added the code above for reference.

Comment: @mm8 My ItemsControl is bound to a ldependency property Engineer of type List which holds the engineers for each area.

Comment: Is EngineerCommand defined in the Engineer class? Or is Engineer and EngineerCommand defined in the same view model class?

Comment: @mm8 No, the EngineerCommand is defined in the View Model separately.

Comment: @NayiaAntoniadou: So Engineer and EngineerCommand are defined in the same view model class? See my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

If the `EngineerCommand` command is defined in the same view model class as the collection to which you bind the `ItemsSource` property of the `ItemsControl` to (`Engineer`), you should use a `RelativeSource` for your binding(s) in the `ItemTemplate`:

```
<MouseBinding Command="{Binding DataContext.EngineerCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" ... />
```

Comment: Will this be added in the MainWindow ?

Comment: In the `Engineers_UC` where the `MouseBinding` is defined. Where else?

Comment: I have added it where the MouseBinding is in Engineers_UC but It still does not work!

Comment: Please provide a MCVE of your issue then: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. No one will be able to help you any further based on the information you have provided.